# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library XAMPP WINDOWS 10

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, pecl

Yes this has been asked many times before and I tried all the answers I could found

(edit)
to be clear I instaled xampp but at the moment i am building a command line utility. this means I don't use xampp and php.exe is throwing the error

I was wondering if someone could clarify this?
I got the above mention error when installing pdo_ibm 
And running `php –I` on the command line

The complete error message (some in dutch it says `can't find module` ):

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_ibm'
>   (tried: C:\xampp2\php\ext\pdo_ibm (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.),
>   C:\xampp2\php\ext\php_pdo_ibm.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.))
>   in Unknown on line 0

I checked and tried all things mentioned below 
Nothing seemed to work

In my php.ini I have got:

```
extension=pdo_ibm  also tried using the format php_pdo_ibm.dll
extension_dir="C:\xampp2\php\ext" also tried without drive letter
```

the php_pdo_ibm.dll is in C:\xampp2\php\ext
and there are read and execute rights on the file 
I also tried running setup_xampp.bat

I hope someone can help

Comment: which version of xampp you are trying to install?

Comment: it is running on XAMPP Version: 7.2.9

Comment: In my case whenever any module is missing I just searched for its dll file over internet.

Comment: well the, problem is the dll is there and it has execute and read rights

Comment: if you stop and restart xampp then it gives you same error?

Comment: well the error is not while starting xampp or using xampp  I am building a commandline tool at the moment so its php.exe that creats the error